# Let $w$ be a primitive root of a unit of order 3, prove that $(1-w+w^2)(1+w-w^2)=4$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

The title is the statement of the problem.

I did the following:

$(1-w+w^2)(1+w-w^2)=$

$1+w-w^2-w-w^2+w^3+w^2+w^3-w^4=$

$1-w^2+w^3+w^3-w^4=$

$1-w^2+1+1-w^4=4$, * then,by definition of primitive root of order 3*

$w^4+w^2-1=0$ and the problem is that from here I do not know how to continue. I tried to make the following change of variables: $z=w^2$ then $w^4+w^2-1=0$ becomes $z^2+z-1=0$ but it is not right because this equation has only two solutions and the other has four. So I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: First: remove all those $4$'s from the right side of your chain of equalities. You want to _end up_ with a $4$, not begin there. Then since you know $w^3 = 1$ you know something useful about $w^4$.

Comment: I think you're doing the problem in the wrong direction. You are trying to prove P => Q, and you begin your proof by saying assume Q. I'm not sure if your proposition is true, but I start by assuming your hypothesis and deriving the conclusion, as @EthanBolker mentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $w^3=1$ and $1+w+w^2=0$
$$=(1-w+w^2)(1+w-w^2)$$
$1+w^2=-w$ and $1+w=-w^2$
$$=(-w-w)(-w^2-w^2)$$
$$=(2w)(2w^2)$$
$$=4w^3$$
$$=4(1)=4$$

Comment: Why do you say that $1+w+w^2=0$?

Comment: Because the $1,w,w^2$ are cube roots of unity when $w^3=1$ and $1+w+w^2=0$

Answer (score 2):

$\,4 - (1 - w + w^2) (1 + w - w^2) = (1 + w + w^2) (3 - 3 w + w^2)\,$
where $\,1 + w + w^2\,$ is the irreducible polynomial for a primitive cube root of $1$.

Another way is to multiply the product by $\,1-w\,$ and expand
 $\,(1 - w + w^2) (1 + w - w^2)(1 - w) = 1 - w - w^2 + 3w^3 - 3w^4 + w^5.\,$ Now use the cube root property to get
 $\,w^3 = 1,\, w^4 = w,\, w^5 = w^2\,$ and
$\,1 - w - w^2 + 3 - 3w + w^2 = 4(1 - w).\,$ The original product must be $4.$

Answer (score 1):

We wanted to show that $$(1-w+w^2)(1+w-w^2)=4$$

After expansion, you show that it is equivalent to

$$1-w^2+1+1-w^4=4$$

$$3-w^2-w^4=4$$

which is equivalent to 
$$1+w^2+w^4=0$$

(remark: note that you made a typo and obtained $-1$ in the original post)

Since $w^3=1$,

this is equivalent to $$1+w^2+w=0$$

which is a true statement since

$$1+w+w^2=\frac{1-w^3}{1-w}=\frac{1-1}{1-w}=0$$